# Feature Admin tool gives AccessDenied error

Tags: permissions, administration, security

I'm using the [Feature Admin Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/) to discover faulty features on my SharePoint 2010 farm. However, when I click the "Find Faulty Feature in Farm", it throws this error:

```
---------------------------
An error has occured!
---------------------------
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetAllWebsOfSite(String bstrUrl, Object& pvarWebs, Object& pvarWebIds, Object& pvarParentWebs, Object& pvarLangs, Object& pvarTitles, Object& pvarUIVersions, Object& pvarFlags, Object& pvarWebTemplates, Object& pvarConfigurations, Object& pvarMasterUrls, Object& pvarCustomMasterUrls)

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SPWebCollectionProvider.GetWebsData(String[]& strNames, String[]& strServiceRelUrls, Guid[]& guidWebIds, Int32[]& nLanguages, String[]& strTitles, String[]& strDescriptions, String[]& strCreationTimes, String[]& strModifiedTimes, Boolean[]& bUserIsWebAdmins, Int32[]& nWebTemplates, Int16[]& nProvisionConfigs, Int16[]& nMeetingCounts, Int32[]& nUIVersions, Int32[]& nFlags, String[]& strMasterUrls, String[]& strCustomMasterUrls)

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.EnsureWebsData()

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseCollection.GetEnumerator()

   at FeatureAdmin.FrmMain.btnFindFaultyFeature_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
---------------------------
OK   Cancel   
---------------------------
```

I'm admin on the box and on SharePoint, as well as on the farm. Any thoughts as to why it throws this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any site collections which are in any of the following state within Central Administration > Application Management > Site Collection Quotas and Locks:

- Adding content prevented
- Read-only (blocks additions, updates, and deletions)
- No access

You may need to change it to the **Not Locked** state before running the tool.